# UITableView height of a section

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that has 3 sections. My individual cells vary in height (collapse-expand).
I need a way to figure out the height of each individual section, i.e. the sum of cell heights in each section. Preferably without calculating everything the tableView already has done each time I need it.

I there a way to deduce or access such a value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you look at [-rectForSection:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW63) (and possibly also `-rectForFooterInSection:`)?

Comment: It even takes into account the expanding/collapsing cells without me having to do anything. Perfect. Thank you so much (especially because it was right there in the manual in front of me all the time).

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to calculate the value, however there is a way. If your cells have a fixed height it's just the many rows multiplied by their fixed height for each section.

If you have varying height in the cells too, I'd go for an array which holds the total height for each section, just calculate it once and keep it cached there. If the section is collapsed you just need the section header height else it's the value in the array.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I had started to design a solution like the one you suggest but the overhead/extra code it would generate made me ask in here, luckily. :)

Comment: @RickiG if it comes to performance I think the above solution is not ideal, put a breakpoint in your heightForRowAtIndexPath and see how often it is called, however it is most convenient :)