# Change colour condition in tableviewcell iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a standard tableview with 5 sections and it has 2 height conditions. So question is how can I change cell background colour when it expanded and set it to default colour (black) when minimised.

[image: Here is my tableview]

Comment: can you please eloborate your question.

Comment: please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021939/uitableview-height-of-a-section

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below instructions.

1. Set `BOOL` flag for each section
2. Check in `cellForRow` method whether the current section is Expanded or not.
3. If the section is expanded, then change the cell background color to `Blue` else set the color to `Black`.
4. To set the flag for each section, **initially** you can set `NO` to each section and save in an Array.
5. Whenever a section is expanded or collapsed, you need to change the `flag` values accordingly.
6. You can manage height also by checking the same condition in `HeightForRow` mwthod.